# Volumetrics look good in viewport but render weird

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

So I'm creating an underwater scene in Eevee using volumetrics for light rays. It has dark and deep colors with shadows and stuff in the viewport, but once I render it, it looks terrible. I'm pretty sure this problem is caused by the volumetric lighting cause when I turn that off everything looks fine, but I need it to make everything look underwater. The blend file is a too big to post here.

Here's the blender viewport:
[image: Viewport]

And here's the final render:
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Can you edit your post to make the images part of the post itself?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Is this rendered in Eevee?

Comment: Yes, everything is in Eevee